# Exclude all attrs auto-generated methods from sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc, python-attrs

I have a simple attrs data class:

```
from attrs import frozen

@frozen
class Person
    raw: str
```

I document it with the simplest `*.rst` file:

```
.. autoclass:: api.main.person.Person
   :members:
   :exclude-members: __init__
```

but if I need to remove `__eq__`, `__hash__` etc. as well, Is there a better way?

Comment: Have you set `autodoc_default_options` in conf.py? https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#confval-autodoc_default_options

Comment: @mzjn I actually don't *always* want to exclude `__init__` (`__eq__` etc.) ... only if they were bolier(ly)-plated by attrs

Comment: Does it help if you add the `:no-special-members:` option to `autoclass`?

Comment: no, it doesn't, I still see the `__init__` ... I wonder if you can somehow do an attrs "trick" to remove their auto-generated docstring: `Method generated by attrs for class Person.` ... If I can remove that then I'm done because sphinx (can) ignore methods without doc strings

Comment: I am trying to understand why you get `__eq__` etc in the output. I don't see them unless I add `:special-members:`.

Comment: ah sorry, I was maybe unclear - I have *many* attrs classes, each with its own set of auto generated methods. I want auto-generated methods to not appear in the sphinx doc

Comment: To me, it looks as if the default is to exclude the autogenerated methods from the output. I cannot explain why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: I'm seeing the same behaviour as reported by @OrenIshShalom.  Does anyone have a solution for this?  For example, does Sphinx have any way to exclude docstrings which match a given regex?  Or (slightly lower level) a hook through which docstrings are passed, so that I could write my own function which looks for "generated by attrs" and delete the entire docstring if it matches.